# How to automatically start a plugin in an RCP product?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP product which consists of several plugins and features. One of those plugins is a background service that I want to automatically start when the product is launched.

I have tried a couple of things. There is the "Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded" option inside the manifest file, but since there is no reference to this background service from my main plugin, it doesn't work.

There is also the "Auto-Start" option in the plugin list in the run configuration, which works when I run the product from Eclipse, but doesn't work when I make an actual build since the run configuration is not part of the build.

How can I achieve this? Is this something to be done on the product level, or on the plugin level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the Run Configuration 'Auto-Start' option is in the 'xxx.product' file for your RCP. Look at the 'Configuration' tab and add the plug-in to the 'Start Levels' section.

You might also consider using an [OSGi Service](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGiServices/article.html).

If this is an e4 RCP you can also use AddOns or start the code in the LifeCycle class.

Comment: That Configuration tab is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!